# PhoneGap + jqueryMobile TextToSpeech

Tags: android, cordova, jquery-mobile, text-to-speech

is it possible to implement a text to speech via Phonegap/Jquery Mobile? Are there any other opportunities?

Best regards, Alex

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you have to try this plugin: https://github.com/macdonst/TTS